# Java Core. Модификатор static

Tags: java

"В чем преимущество использования модификатора static?"
зачем маркировать метод или поле как static, что явно указать что это поле принадлежит именно этому классу, если в примере:

```
public class SimpleClass {

private int field; 

}
```

Поле field принадлежит классу Class.
Так в чем тогда разница?
Только в удобстве доступа к тому или иному полю или методу, например:

```
Class.field;
```

Вместо использования геттеров и сеттеров и явной инициализации класса или есть еще какие-то явные преимущества использования этого модификатора?

**Update 1**

Пишет, что использования статических методов дает преимущество, так как статические методы хорошо подходят как методы утилиты.
На статические методы не работают с не статическими полями, получается, что для того, чтобы передать какое-то значение в статический метод, нам нужно передавать или статические переменные или value, которое мы сразу будем вводить в параметры метода? Но если я хочу использовать в каком-то сервисе, статический метод, для изменения нестатического поля из другого класса, мне всегда будет выдавать ошибку? Разве это удобно? Нужно подстраиваться как-то под эти ситуации или есть уже решения?

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы заметили при попытке передачи в статический метод класса переменную не статическую я получил ошибку... Это не самый удобный выбор, как по мне.. на этот момент.

Comment: У каждого отдельного объекта SimpleClass будет свой field, если вы объявите field как static, то он будет принадлежать классу и будет только один. Также часто используют модификатор static при объявлении констант.

Comment: @Arsenicum обновил вопрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте код текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Вы очень сильно путаетесь. У вас ошибка не о том, что вы передаете в статический метод, не статическую переменную. А о том что вы к ней обращаетесь в статическом методе `main()`.

Comment: @trembling11, а вы попробуй сделать это вне статического контекста.

Comment: @Vartlok ага, все по этой части я понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Основное отличие `static` полей и методов в том, что они существуют в контексте класса, а не отдельного экземпляра.

Соответственно `static` поля существуют в одном экземпляре. А при работе в `static` методах нельзя обращаться к не статик контенту, потому что его там просто не существует. Нельзя использовать ключевое слово `this`, но можно и нужно взаимодействовать с объектами переданными как параметры.

В вашем примере ошибка не про передачу в статик метод, а про обращение к ней из статик контента. В итоге код должен быть преобразован в:

```
System.out.println(this.value);
```

но т.к. переменной `this` в этом контексте нет, то и код будет не правильным. Если же вы попробуете что-то такое:

```
class A {
    private int a = 0;

    public void inc() {
        System.out.println(Util.changeValue(a));
    }
}
```

То всё будет работать. Только прощу заметить, что исходное значение в классе `A` не поменяется, метод назван неправильно.

Так же `static` поля принято использовать для набора констант, только еще с модификатором `final`.

Comment: а можно несколько слов о this и его совмещением с static методами? Или никакого совмещения нету? Просто this не можно использовать в статических методах?

Comment: @trembling11 ключевое слово `this` не имеет смысла в `static` методах и следовательно использовать его там нельзя.

Comment: @trembling11, `this` - обозначает ссылку на текущий объект класса, `static method` - нет необходимости создавать объект для использования. Вы вызвали статичный метод (не привязан ни к одному объекту) и попытались передать `this.value` (но `this` никуда не ссылается, объект `JavaInheritance` не был создан). В результате получается противоречие, если использовать `this` и `static`.

Comment: @Arsenicum  спасибо, теперь уже что-то обрисовалось, а то я вообще не понимал причины использования этого модификатора и очень часто горел на этом вопросе на собеседованиях.

Answer (score 0):

Может так будет проще. Статический контекст не требует создания объекта класса конструктором new. Статический объект создается сразу,  при первом обращении к его  методам.
Если вам не надо создавать множественные копии ваших объектов, а просто необходимо получить результат некой операции, то статический объект это самое нужное. Большинство  утилитарных  библиотек используют именно статический подход.